# Does sIFR support Hebrew and other right-to-left (rtl) languages?

Tags: sifr, sifr3

I'm doing a site in Hebrew which of course runs from right-to-left. Will this be supported by sIFR? The site is currently using sIFR v2. I'm guessing that doesn't have support but what about sIFR3?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know, but you *really* should use CSS embedded fonts instead of sIFR because of usability, accessibility and performance reasons. However, one might choose to use sIFR if [having the custom fonts in IE] is an extremely important thing.

Answer (score 0):

sIFR does not and will not have RTL support.